# Include copying and pasting the row, from which it gets its name to create a new sheet, into the new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the attached code which adds a new sheet for each row in a master spreadsheet.  This code also names each spreadsheet by a specific cell of the row, and then loops to the next row to go again.  However, I also need the code to also copy the entire row and past to cell A7 or A8 of each sheet that it creates before going on to the next sheet but I can't get that code.  Can someone help me?

I have tried a few different codes but I am still new to coding so what I tried did not do anything.  I ended up with no errors but also nothing added to my spreadsheets.  The code that I have does create the spreadsheets and names them correctly, but that one piece is all that is missing.

```
Sub NewSheetPerName()

lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source Data (Target 1)").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 7 To lastRow
    Set curWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count))
    curWS.Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source Data (Target 1)").Cells(x, 1)
Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```vb
Sub NewSheetPerName()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, curWS As Worksheet, x As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.WorkSheets("Source Data (Target 1)")

    For x = 7 To ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set curWS = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.count))
        curWS.Name = ws.Cells(x, 1).Value
        ws.Rows(x).Copy curWS.range("A7") 'copy row to new sheet
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: You are my hero!! This is perfect and did exactly what I needed it to do!  Thank you so much for your help!!